# Implementation of visitor pattern

Tags: java

We implemented a Inventory for in a game as a school assignment. The inventory is implemented using an ArrayList which contain items. There are different types of items: Grenades, RocketLaunchers, etc.

We need to be able to store every item in an arraylist. However, some items have constraints ( e.g. there can only be 6 grenades in the inventory.)

We aren't allowed to use instanceof. So we implemented a visitor pattern which adds the grenade to our Inventory and we used a different list for grenades than for the other items. During the evaluation of the assignment we were told we should store every item in the same list. We aren't allowed to keep count of the grenades inside the inventory. We should count the number of grenades before we try to add a grenade to the inventory. But we have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The title mentions the visitor pattern. Have you tried implementing it? What's the problem?

Comment: We had implemented it to add the grenades to the specific list and the other items to the general list. The problem was counting the grenades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visitor pattern as you guessed is the right choice. But implemented, it would look like this: (pseudo-code):

```
interface InventoryVisitor{
    onGrenade(theGrenade);
    onDefaultItem(theItem);
}

class DefaultItem{
    visit(visitor){visitor.onDefaultItem(this);}
}

class Grenade extends DefaultItem{
    visit(visitor){visitor.onGrenade(this);}
}
```

then, you call `visit` on each item of the inventoryList with an implementation of InventoryVisitor that e.g. counts how many grenades there are and throws an exception, if there are more then six.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have some interface `Item` and on that interface you can have a method `getItemType` which returns an enum value.

```
public enum ItemType {
    Grenade,
    RocketLauncher
}

public interface Item {
    ItemType getItemType();
}
```

It is not very fancy but you can at least ask the item what type it is without using `instanceof` and you don't have to use the visitor pattern. But maybe the pattern was part of the assignment?

Comment: That's actually a bad advice, since using `enum` the way you described in long-term ends up with tons of `switch`es in the code which make the code difficult to maintain and extend. For instance, when a new type appears you end up with a lot of places to change. And in bigger projects that's not even feasible. The Visitor pattern is one of solutions to this problem.

Comment: @AdamDyga We're talking about a **school assignment**! Don't over engineer.

Comment: in my opinion even students should always learn the right approach from the very beginning

Comment: @AdamDyga In my opinion even students should be aware of the KISS principle. I disagree with you.

Comment: We had thought of the enum solution, but kept it as a last resort because the usage of enums is discouraged. Plus the switch statement is considered a code smell. The whole point of our project ( we need to implement an entire game is to learn to code according to patterns and the GRASP principles.)